# Laravel 5.1 FatalThrowableError in ProviderRepository.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i installed the package [kbwebs/multiauth](https://github.com/Kbwebs/MultiAuth) but I have this error :

```
FatalThrowableError in ProviderRepository.php line 146:
Fatal error: Class 'Kbwebs\MultiAuth\AuthServiceProvider' not found
```

I don't understand why i have this error, my app.php is correctly configure :

```
'providers' => [
     (...)
     Kbwebs\MultiAuth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
     Kbwebs\MultiAuth\PasswordResets\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
     (...)
],
```

Composer.json :

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "chrisbjr/api-guard": "^2.3",
    "kbwebs/multiauth": "~1.0"
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the Laravel Cache.
I clear the cache and upload again the projet on my server.

Comment: @YaShChaudhary composer clear-cache or composer clearcache

Answer (score 1):

for me, someone on the team added the new libraries and I simply needed to run `composer install` to get the new libraries.